# How to remove warning message in logstash output

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am getting some warning message in my console such as:

> C:/Users/MayurGavali/Desktop/ELK/logstash-7.5.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/awesome_print-1.7.0/lib/awesome_print/formatters/base_formatter.rb:31: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated

I don't want this deprecated warning message to be printed in my console.

What code should be written to remove this deprecated warning message in filter section?

I tried using remove field but this doesnt work for me.

[image]

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and message gets printed quite often. Any insight into how you managed to resolve it?